# Comparing Octave ML Results Vs. R results

Tags: r, statistics, machine-learning, octave

#### R Code:

`my.data <- mtcars[,c(1,3)] # Which has only two columns mpg, disp`

`lm(mpg~disp,data=my.data) #R Code for fitting a regression line`

R Output:

```
Call:
  lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = my.data)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)         disp  
     29.59985     -0.04122
```

Writing R dataset to the disk file

```
write.table(my.data,'~/Downloads/mtcars',sep=",",row.name=F,col.names=F)
```

#### Octave Code:

```
cd ~/Downloads
data=load('mtcars') # Using R dataset to fit the model
x=data(:,2)
y=data(:,1) 
cd ~/Dropbox/ML/mlclass-ex1-004/mlclass-ex1 %without any errors
xn=featureNormalize(x) # feature Normalizing with mean and std 
x1=[ones(length(x),1),xn]
theta=zeros(size(x1,2),1)
g=gradientDescent(x1,y,theta,alpha=.1,10000)
```

Output of g is:

```
g =
20.0906
-5.0277
```

If you look at the intercept and coefficient of disp; there is no near match to the R output and octave output.

Does anyone have the idea where this difference come from? and which one is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You normalized features in the Octave code. Doing the same in R gets similar results.

```
R> mtcars$normalized_disp <- as.numeric(scale(mtcars$disp))
R> lm(mpg ~ normalized_disp, data = mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ normalized_disp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  normalized_disp  
         20.091           -5.108
```